# Launch Application Using Target File

Tags: objective-c, macos, launching-application

Using NSWorkSpace launchApplication and all is fine if using an application file, but what if one would like to launch an application using a target file like untitled.rtf

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:selection]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-[NSWorkspace openFile:WithApplication:]` like so:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Myfiles/untitled.rtf"
    withApplication:@"TextEdit"];
```

Or, if one just wants to open a file with the default application for that file, use `-[NSWorkspace openFile:]` like so:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Myfiles/untitled.rtf"];
```

The be sure to check the [documentation for NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details and other related methods.

Comment: Ok, but the whole point is to open the file without having to know the application name.  I have a solution that will do this and will answer it whenI can

Answer (score 1):

This will launch the proper application with only the target file.....

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments: @[@"/somewhere/untitled.rtf];
[task launch];
```

Comment: Too much work when NSWorkspace has a method to do this already. See my answer for details.